# Wireguard server and Open VPN connection to VPN provider

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, wireguard

I've been trying to setup a double-hop VPN connection. First step is an Open VPN connection from this guide: https://github.com/mr-canoehead/vpn_client_gateway/wiki/Installation-Guide

It gives an option to use Mullvad and select different servers from a web UI. It works great alongside PiHole.

After that, I wanted to use Wireguard to establish a server on that same Pi, so I could connect with my laptop and my phone when I am away and not only access LAN, but also use the VPN connection from the gateway. I assumed this double-hop would be difficult (tried to do it before with two OpenVPN conf, but failed), so I looked up and found this:
[Wireguard server and openvpn client - Forward traffic from wg0 to tun0 (openvpn tunnel)](https://superuser.com/questions/1403830/wireguard-server-and-openvpn-client-forward-traffic-from-wg0-to-tun0-openvpn?newreg=08d088c3118d4bf99a63aaae18bf37a5)

This gave me hope and decided to give Wireguard a go. Everything went great, both laptop and phone connect without problems, but they don't have internet access. First I thought I had to add the rule to table 4 instead of 7 (as in the 2nd link), but didn't work. Then I tried 10 and 11, also no luck. Tried to comment on that solution, so I maybe get help there, but don't have enough rep.

This is my route -n output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.16.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun-outgoing
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
10.9.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
10.16.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun-outgoing
128.0.0.0       10.16.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun-outgoing
185.212.170.162 10.0.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

This is my iconfig output:

```
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e871:c051:3610:acb4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:c7:2f:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1006  bytes 258399 (252.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 657  bytes 92999 (90.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2422  bytes 156903 (153.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2422  bytes 156903 (153.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun-outgoing: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.16.0.3  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.16.0.3
        inet6 fe80::b100:7525:9bb7:31c1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdda:d0d0:cafe:1302::1001  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 161  bytes 55317 (54.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 182  bytes 24177 (23.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.9.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.9.0.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 4 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::94f8:3b8:7b18:6c6f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:92:7a:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 547  bytes 133449 (130.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 103  bytes 16134 (15.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note: tun-outgoing is the VPN gateway, wg0 is Wireguard server.

Also, I've setup ddclient to update Cloudflare and have a port forwarded over Mullvad, but since connecting clients is working, I guess that is not the problem.

So, to sum it up:

- VPN gateway over OpenVPN – working.
- PiHole – working.
- Wireguard – connects, but clients have no internet connection if the
  gateway is up.

Does anyone have any idea what might I do? I have a feeling I'm missing some dumb obvious thing, but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable outgoing NAT on the OpenVPN connection? // Also, multiple routing tables aren’t really required for this. Most of it will “just work”.

Comment: You mean through the iptables or? Not sure I understand, still not that well-versed in all this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes. The OpenVPN provider will not be able to route packages from networks other than 10.16.0.3/16 back to you because it doesn’t know you have these networks. NAT solves this problem by “hiding” your networks.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Could you maybe tell me at least how the command should look like approximately? I've tried entering: sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE and then connect from my phone, but still no internet.

Comment: You’ll want to apply this to `tun-outgoing` instead of `eth0`. Though `eth0` may also need it if you want to access devices on your network without setting up routing.

Comment: It is finally working!! I can't thank you enough, I have been struggling with this setup for months. A thousand times – thank you! Just one more question if you will: when I run the gateway iptables rules (from a preloaded script) they block x11vnc which is on port 5900, so what would be the iptables command to get it working again? I've tried iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s 10.0.1.1/255.255.255.0 -dport 5900 -j ACCEPT, but with no luck... But even without this, you have helped me immensely!